# Unable to download mp4 from sharepoint 2010 on mobile, but non-mobile works fine

Tags: mobile, sharepoint-2010, session-state

We've got a SharePoint site with a custom application that is designed for both web and mobile that we are trying to upgrade from SP2007 to SP2010.  The site contains playlists of mp4 files.  We have asp.net session state active on the site for use within the custom application.  We also rewrite urls to HTTPS.

The files are stored on disk and accessed through a virtual directory.

When the files are accessed through the SP2010 web site (non-mobile), the mp4 file plays just fine.

When the exact same url is accessed from a mobile browser, we receive the message:

```
Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true, either in a
configuration file or in the Page directive. Please also make sure that
System.Web.SessionStateModule or a custom session state module is included in the
<configuration>\<system.web>\<httpModules> section in the application configuration.
```

We DO have the SessionStateModule declared in <configuration>\<system.webServer>\<modules> as follows:

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" preCondition="" />
```

We have also tried without the preCondition, and with preCondition="integratedMode".

An example of the url is https://example.com/Assets/Job63/8f9e85d5-d7f3-4536-a9b1-69537b7da9bf/Previews/0568145f-b314-4354-a081-d72019a42d11.mp4 (the domain has been changed to protect the innocent).

The virtual directory is /Assets and it points to a c:\Assets directory.

This behavior occurs even using FireFox and changing the user agent to simulate mobile, so it appears to be something intercepting mobile requests.

None of the other sessionstate answers on the site appear to cover this problem.

We also have the SessionStateModule declared in the IIS Module list for the website.

What may be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to resolve the issue by putting a web.config file containing the following into the assets folder.  It is apparently the aggressive mobile redirect that SharePoint does in SP2010 that causes the problem, as explained at the following url - http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-sharepoint-2010-mobile-redirect/  .

web.config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <browserCaps>
      <result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
    </browserCaps>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```